# Why does my reactiveVal code fail in R Shiny when the same code works when part of a reactive?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, reactive, shiny-reactivity

When users select a date using the date range input, I want to convert the format of their selected date and then treat it like a character.

I can get my code to work when it's embedded in a larger reactive to filter my dataset, but I can't get it to work as it's own value. Because I need to use this character string across many areas of my app, I'd rather just write the code once as it's own reactiveVal than having to embed it within larger reactives.

Here's the code that fails (I only moved the from_date outside of the larger reactive):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(stringr)



ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinydashboard(),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Resource View", fluid = TRUE,
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         div(id = "inputs",
                             dateRangeInput(
                                 inputId = "date_filter",
                                 label = "Filter by Month and Year",
                                 start = today(),
                                 end = (today() + 90),
                                 min = "Apr-2021",
                                 max = NULL,
                                 format = "M-yyyy",
                                 startview = "month",
                                 weekstart = 0,
                                 language = "en",
                                 separator = " to ",
                                 width = NULL,
                                 autoclose = TRUE
                             ),
                             br()),
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         DT::DTOutput("resource_table"),

                     )
                 )
        )
        )
    )
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    from_date <- reactiveVal({ tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1]))
    
    
    from_date <- from_date %>%
        mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
        separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
        mutate(month = case_when(
            month == "01" ~ "jan",
            month == "02" ~ "feb",
            month == "03" ~ "mar",
            month == "04" ~ "apr",
            month == "05" ~ "may",
            month == "06" ~ "jun",
            month == "07" ~ "jul",
            month == "08" ~ "aug",
            month == "09" ~ "sep",
            month == "10" ~ "oct",
            month == "11" ~ "nov",
            month == "12" ~ "dec",
            TRUE~ "ERROR"
        )) %>%
        unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
    
    from_date <- parse_character(from_date$month_year)
    })
    
    
    select_values <- reactive({
        data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
                       education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "graudate", "student", "student", "nurse", "doctor"),
                       fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
                       aug_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5))
        

        
        
        
        to_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[2]))
        
        to_date <- to_date %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")  
        
        to_date <- parse_character(to_date$month_year)
        
        
        data %>%
            dplyr::select(employee, education, fte_max_capacity, project,
                          from_date():to_date)
        
    })
    
    output$resource_table <- renderDT({
        select_values()
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And here's the code working perfectly when the from_date is embeded in the reactive for select_values().

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets) 
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(janitor)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)



ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinydashboard(),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Resource View", fluid = TRUE,
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         div(id = "inputs",
                             dateRangeInput(
                                 inputId = "date_filter",
                                 label = "Filter by Month and Year",
                                 start = today(),
                                 end = (today() + 90),
                                 min = "Apr-2021",
                                 max = NULL,
                                 format = "M-yyyy",
                                 startview = "month",
                                 weekstart = 0,
                                 language = "en",
                                 separator = " to ",
                                 width = NULL,
                                 autoclose = TRUE
                             ),
                             br()),
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         DT::DTOutput("resource_table"),

                     )
                 )
        )
        )
    )
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    
    
    select_values <- reactive({
        data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
                       education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "graudate", "student", "student", "nurse", "doctor"),
                       fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
                       aug_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5))
        

        from_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1]))
            
            
            from_date <- from_date %>%
                mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
                separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
                mutate(month = case_when(
                    month == "01" ~ "jan",
                    month == "02" ~ "feb",
                    month == "03" ~ "mar",
                    month == "04" ~ "apr",
                    month == "05" ~ "may",
                    month == "06" ~ "jun",
                    month == "07" ~ "jul",
                    month == "08" ~ "aug",
                    month == "09" ~ "sep",
                    month == "10" ~ "oct",
                    month == "11" ~ "nov",
                    month == "12" ~ "dec",
                    TRUE~ "ERROR"
                )) %>%
                unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
            
            from_date <- parse_character(from_date$month_year)
        
        
        to_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[2]))
        
        to_date <- to_date %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")  
        
        to_date <- parse_character(to_date$month_year)
        
        
        data %>%
            dplyr::select(employee, education, fte_max_capacity, project,
                          from_date:to_date)
        
    })
    
    output$resource_table <- renderDT({
        select_values()
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In the answer, I'd really appreciate if you could also explain why your solution works and why my original attempt failed. Thank you!

Edit: Tried clarifying from_date by using variable names, but the app still crashes

```
    from_date <- reactiveVal({
        
        start_date <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1]))
        
        
        date1 <- start_date %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
        
        date1 <- parse_character(date1$month_year)
    })
```

Comment: You are assigning three different things to  `from_date <- {...}`; the later definition are replacing the first. Use different variable names to make things more clear. And in the the re-write you no longer seem to be in a reactive context. To get the value of a reactive object, use `from_date()`. In the case that works, that code is include `select_values <- reactive({ .. })`. But you don't seem to have such a wrapper in the new code.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks for the suggestion! I just tried clarifying the names within from_date (see above edit), but it still crashes instantly.

Comment: Specific error is:   Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)  Which I don't understand because it's wrapped within reactiveVal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do `from_date` in one reactive.

```
  from_date <- reactive({
    fdate1 <- tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1])) 
    fdate2 <- fdate1 %>%
      mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
      separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
      mutate(month = case_when(
        month == "01" ~ "jan",
        month == "02" ~ "feb",
        month == "03" ~ "mar",
        month == "04" ~ "apr",
        month == "05" ~ "may",
        month == "06" ~ "jun",
        month == "07" ~ "jul",
        month == "08" ~ "aug",
        month == "09" ~ "sep",
        month == "10" ~ "oct",
        month == "11" ~ "nov",
        month == "12" ~ "dec",
        TRUE~ "ERROR"
      )) %>%
      unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
    fdate <- parse_character(fdate2$month_year)
    fdate
  })
```

Same goes for `to_date`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! So in line with the comment from @MrFlick, R was getting confused by trying to do so many things in one reactive. When I split each of those 3 segments into it's own reactive, I was able to make it work. If anyone knows a tighter way to get to the same end point, happy to look at other options:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(htmltools)
library(lubridate)
library(DT)
library(stringr)



ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinydashboard(),
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Resource View", fluid = TRUE,
                 sidebarLayout(
                     sidebarPanel(
                         div(id = "inputs",
                             dateRangeInput(
                                 inputId = "date_filter",
                                 label = "Filter by Month and Year",
                                 start = today(),
                                 end = (today() + 90),
                                 min = "Apr-2021",
                                 max = NULL,
                                 format = "M-yyyy",
                                 startview = "month",
                                 weekstart = 0,
                                 language = "en",
                                 separator = " to ",
                                 width = NULL,
                                 autoclose = TRUE
                             ),
                             br()),
                     ),
                     mainPanel(
                         DT::DTOutput("resource_table"),
                         
                     )
                 )
        )
    )
)
server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    from_date_unclean <- reactive({
        
        tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[1])) 
        })
        
    from_date_midway <- reactive({
        from_date_unclean() %>%
            mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
            separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
            mutate(month = case_when(
                month == "01" ~ "jan",
                month == "02" ~ "feb",
                month == "03" ~ "mar",
                month == "04" ~ "apr",
                month == "05" ~ "may",
                month == "06" ~ "jun",
                month == "07" ~ "jul",
                month == "08" ~ "aug",
                month == "09" ~ "sep",
                month == "10" ~ "oct",
                month == "11" ~ "nov",
                month == "12" ~ "dec",
                TRUE~ "ERROR"
            )) %>%
            unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_")
    })
        
    from_date <- reactive({
        parse_character(from_date_midway()$month_year)
    })
    
    
    to_date_unclean <- reactive({
        tibble(date = as.character(input$date_filter[2]))
    })
    
    to_date_midway <- reactive({
        to_date_unclean() %>%
        mutate(date = str_remove_all(date, "-..$")) %>%
        separate(date, into = c("year", "month"), sep = "-") %>%
        mutate(month = case_when(
            month == "01" ~ "jan",
            month == "02" ~ "feb",
            month == "03" ~ "mar",
            month == "04" ~ "apr",
            month == "05" ~ "may",
            month == "06" ~ "jun",
            month == "07" ~ "jul",
            month == "08" ~ "aug",
            month == "09" ~ "sep",
            month == "10" ~ "oct",
            month == "11" ~ "nov",
            month == "12" ~ "dec",
            TRUE~ "ERROR"
        )) %>%
        unite("month_year", c(month, year), sep = "_") 
    })
    
    to_date <- reactive({
        parse_character(to_date_midway()$month_year)
    })
        


    
    select_values <- reactive({
        data <- tibble(employee = c("Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Justin", "Corey","Sibley", "Lisa", "NA"),
                       education = c("graudate", "student", "student", "graudate", "student", "student", "nurse", "doctor"),
                       fte_max_capacity = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                       project = c("big", "medium", "small", "medium", "small", "small", "medium", "medium"),
                       aug_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       sep_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       oct_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5),
                       nov_2021 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5))
        
        
        
        

        
        
        data %>%
            dplyr::select(employee, education, fte_max_capacity, project,
                          from_date():to_date())
        
    })
    
    output$resource_table <- renderDT({
        select_values()
    })
    
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```